# Gitlab ci build failed to restore packages for asp.net core project

Tags: asp.net-core, continuous-integration, devops, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I was trying to configure a simple pipeline to build and deploy my asp.net core application into shared hosting, however it always failed in restoring Newtonsoft.Json, dispute the project is build-able and fully works on local machine, my ci file looks like the following:

```
image: microsoft/dotnet:latest

stages:
  - build

before_script:
  - dotnet restore -s https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json --packages ./.nuget/

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - "dotnet build"
```

And the error I am getting inside the pipeline is:

```
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.402/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Newtonsoft.Json". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
```

I also tried dotnet restore only, but with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out the problem, I added the Newtonsoft.Json as reference instead of installing it from nuget (actually visual studio added it as reference for me from the quick action), so I remove the reference and install it as package and everything works perfectly